# How to add a value to a comma separated list with sed

Tags: regex, sed

Sample input:

```
common.loader= a # test
commonXloader=a
 common.loader=a
common.loader= a, b
# common.loader=a       
common.loader =
common.loader =#
common.loader = # test
```

Epected:

```
common.loader= <everything before # and newline and comma if there is some value> <argument which i want to insert> <everything after hash and newline>
```

So:

```
common.loader= a, x # test
commonXloader=a
 common.loader=a, x
common.loader= a, b, x
# common.loader=a       
common.loader = x
common.loader = x# 
common.loader = x # test
```

I tried but did not get it working with sed. Closest I got was:

```
sed -r -e 's:((^\s*common\.loader\s*=)(([^#\S]*)(#.*)?))$:\1 x \3:'
```

Comment: could you provide a real expected output?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect so can you instead being generic in expectation, type in what should be output in real time.

Comment: added output. Was first not able because stackoverflow complained that I added to much code. So I removed some test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do the conditional comma (conditional upon there being an existing term), the simplest is to do two substitutions first for just adding the comma, and second for replacing `=,` with `=`:

```
sed -re '/^\s*common\.loader\s*=\s*/ {s/(\s*(#|$))/, x\1/; s/=,/=/}'
```

Note that we do these substitutions only on the right lines using sed's pattern address functionality.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction! My final solution is: `/^\s*common\.loader\s*=\s*/ {s/([^#]*)/\1, x/; s/=\s*,/=/}`

Comment: Ok, that doesn't produce the result you asked for on the first line, or the last line because it swallows the space before the `#` and puts it before the `, x` - but if that's ok then nice work.

Comment: Also if you appreciated my answer then the thing to do here on SO is to vote it up, and really because it does precisely what you asked for you really ought to make it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I would like to vote it up, but I do not have enough points yet :-( If I have enough I will vote it up.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that, np :)